# Magento bestseller block method - where addCategoryFilter not working

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, collection, product-collection, ce-1.9.2.4

we are creating a bestseller block and use the code below. We are facing two problems.

One of which is that when I add a category filter then the method `$collection->addCategoryFilter($category)` just doesn't work and ends up with a blank page. It seems `addCategoryFilter` is not working. All other variables are present and not empty (tested).

**question:** Why is `$collection->addCategoryFilter($category)` not working in the code below?

help appreciated (Magento 1.9.2.4)

```
public function getCollection()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');

    if (Mage::helper('catalog/product_flat')->isEnabled()) {
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinInner(array('e2' => 'catalog_product_flat_' . $storeId), 'e2.entity_id = e.entity_id');
    } else {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'));
    }

    $_category = (int)$this->getCategory() ?: null;
    if ($_category) {
        $_category = 76;
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category);
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category); // gives no result, blank page
    }

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);

    $_limit = (int)$this->getLimit() ?: 3;
    $collection->setPage(1, $_limit);
    return $collection;
}
```

This is the SQL output. It gives some hints, one of which is

- It seems to be returning only simple products (and our store contains configurable products (clothing in sizes): maybe this is a reason?

  `` SELECT SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty`, `order_items`.`name` AS `order_items_name`, `order_items`.`product_id` AS `entity_id`, `e`.`entity_type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e2`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `at_inventory_in_stock`.`is_in_stock` AS `inventory_in_stock` FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_items` INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON `order`.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND `order`.state <> 'canceled' LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped', 'configurable', 'bundle')) AND e.entity_id = order_items.product_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_flat_8` AS `e2` ON e2.entity_id = e.entity_id INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='8' AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '54' INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_inventory_in_stock` ON (at_inventory_in_stock.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND ((at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1) OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=0) OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1)) WHERE (e.type_id = 'simple') GROUP BY `order_items`.`product_id` HAVING (SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > 0) ORDER BY `ordered_qty` desc ``

Comment: What is the other problem? You only mentioned one. Also I think you should change this: $_category = (int)$this->getCategory() ?: null; into this: $_category = (int)$this->getCategory() ? $this->getCategory() : null;

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105690/magento-bestseller-block-product-collection-contains-only-old-hardly-ever-sold

Comment: change  $_category = (int)$this->getCategory() ?: null -- why? it is working fine currently....

Comment: yes you are right I never used the ternary operator like this omitting the return value for true.