# magento bestseller block: product collection contains only old hardly ever sold products

Tags: blocks, collection, product-collection

We are creating a bestseller block and use the code below. With the code below we get a nice list of products. The only problem is that many of these products are either very old - and hardly ever sold. It almost seems that, either:

a. `reports/product_collection` contains very old, not actual data

b. the results are sorted the wrong way around (doesn't seem so)

c. something else? UPDATE: it seems the output is SIMPLE producs only - and we sell configurable products in our fashion store. This is why only some products are showing: these are the only simple products we have.

**question:** How can we get the 'real' bestsellers in the code below?

help appreciated (Magento 1.9.2.4)

```
public function getCollection()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');

    if (Mage::helper('catalog/product_flat')->isEnabled()) {
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinInner(array('e2' => 'catalog_product_flat_' . $storeId), 'e2.entity_id = e.entity_id');
    } else {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'));
    }

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);

    $_limit = (int)$this->getLimit() ?: 3;
    $collection->setPage(1, $_limit);
    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you are getting this old products. But you might try this solution is working nicely for me:

```
public function getBestsellerProducts()
{
    $storeId = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

    // Date
    $date = new Zend_Date();
    $toDate = $date->setDay(1)->getDate()->get('Y-MM-dd');
    $fromDate = $date->subMonth(1)->getDate()->get('Y-MM-dd');

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addPriceData()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addUrlRewrite()
        ->setPageSize(6);

    $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            array('aggregation' => $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales/bestsellers_aggregated_monthly')),
            "e.entity_id = aggregation.product_id AND aggregation.store_id={$storeId} AND aggregation.period BETWEEN '{$fromDate}' AND '{$toDate}'",
            array('SUM(aggregation.qty_ordered) AS sold_quantity')
        )
        ->group('e.entity_id')
        ->order(array('sold_quantity DESC', 'e.created_at'));

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

    return $collection;
}
```

Full article at: http://inchoo.net/magento/bestseller-products-in-magento/